# Couldn't install SSMS: A pending restart is blocking setup from completing

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, ssms-2016

SSMS version : 17.7
[image]

Log file: [Log_file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmMJKLLq-oPlmAP-ky8y18DuP6Kf)

I have SQL Server 2016 and Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. 
I tried reinstalling both tools but the error is still the same.
Some links mention registry values and I tried that as well, but the problem remains the same.

I have restarted the system multiple times, but the restart pending is still showing.
I found a couple of other methods on some sites, tried them as well, but still the error message is showing.

It stops at the point shown below--not sure about Visual Studio 2015 as I'm using VS2017. I have tried repairing VS and SQL Server 2017 as well.
[image]

Comment: tried installation via command line too, not able to install. Here is log  :
https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=e583faeab2280963&id=E583FAEAB2280963%213076&authkey=!AGzOLaCUG4Zkudo

Comment: The error code is 0x80044000, seems to be related with visual studio 2015 KB3095681. I have repaired sql server instance and visual studio too. Removed them and started all over again too. Tried installation with ssms 2016 too it is giving same error.

Comment: Try manually deleting `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools`

Comment: Check that you haven't got a failed Windows update. For instance, the latest Windows 10 update to 1803 may be pending.

Comment: @Larnu Tools directory is not there.

Comment: @PhillipNgan checked that 1803 was successfully installed on 26th. That was the last update.

Comment: Really? That would imply the installation didn't even start. One of the first things it does is create that directory.

Comment: @Larnu the installation does start it shows some progress and then start rolling back the installation after  visual studio 2015 KB3095681

Comment: @PhillipNgan thank you for the idea to check failed update, I googled it and read about registry corruption. so deleted all the failed entries which we related to prerequisites of SSMS and it worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem, after force uninstalling Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated) the SSMS install completed normally. I did this by searching for `vs_isoshell.exe` in `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` and then running `vs_isoshell.exe /uninstall /force` from an administrative command prompt from its folder. In my case this was `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FE948F0DAB52EB8CB5A740A77D8934B9E1A8E301\redist`

Comment: I didn't have Visual Studio 2015 installed - using only 2017, but the same issue trying to install ssms 2017. Removing the vs 2015 shell did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Search the registry with "visual studio 2015" and deleted all the keys which are either related to shell or prerequisites. Repaired the SQL server 2016 and then installed SSMS. It somehow worked for me.

Comment: yeah finally, after days of RnD

Answer (score 2):

In my case, find and delete all registry keys with name "Visual Studio 2015 Shell" and it worked

Comment: Yeah I did the same.

Answer (score 1):

Now i found the solution, i was uninstalled VS 2015(isolated) and concern VS and deleted all "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" and after that restart the pc and installed SSMS2017 again,It was ok.

Comment: Tried that but didn't worked. I had to search through registry and delete all the related keys.

Comment: WARNING:DO NOT DELETE `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` You will not be able to uninstall anything installed before

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i've got it working forcing uninstalling *vs_isoshell.exe* (search for it in *C:\ProgramData\Package Cache* ) then, delete all files and folders in *C:\ProgramData\Package Cache*, reboot and reinstall...